# How to Send e-mail to unverified address with Amazon SES SMTP

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses

I am unable to send e-mails to unverified addresses via Amazon SES SMTP. I can send to arbitrary e-mails with google SMTP - Is there a similar way to do with with SES ?

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you are confused - while you are 'in the sandbox', you can only send emails to verified email addresses (i.e. other email addresses you control) - but once you are 'out of the sandbox', there is no need to verify email addresses that you want to send to - you can use it like any other SMTP server (more or less) and send to anyone, verified or not.